# Update Visual Studio 2019 from 16.8.6 to 16.9.3. Now build projects very slowly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Did anyone notice any significant differences in building projects after the upgrade?

After upgrading to version 16.9.3, projects build very slowly, in addition, I can't do anything while building because the entire Visual Studio process hangs?

I would like to know if only I have such a problem and a possible reinstallation will help?

Comment: Disable the installed anti-malware product to see if it is the cause.

Comment: After upgrading from 16.9.2 to 16.9.3, Visual Studio began to randomly crash and restart on my machine for no apparent reason. There must be something wrong with that version. Version 16.9.4 came out today, apparently. Let us hope Microsoft did not introduce more issues in the new version.

Comment: Disabling the **Visual Studio Rich Navigation [Preview]** extension in VS 16.9.3 seems to have ended Visual Studio's instability and random restarts on my machine. I had installed this extension along with VS 16.9.3, so it seems that the extension was the main culprit of the instability. Hence, it may be good to disable recently installed/updated extensions whenever a new Visual Studio version begins to show quirky behaviour, especially if the extensions are still in the '_preview_' stage.